# Create delegate for struct instance method without boxing the target

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, boxing

I want to create a delegate for a struct instance method without boxing in a performance critical section. Here is an example:

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct(someData);
Action<int> action = new Action<int>(myStruct .ProcessIntValue);
```

However, when I look at the compiler-generated code in dotPeek I can see something like this for the delegate creation:

```
 System.Action<int> action = new System.Action<int>((object) myStruct , __methodptr(ProcessIntValue));
```

Is there a way to avoid this boxing?

Note that I have to use create `Action<int>` delegate because I need it to pass down to the fixed API method that I can't change.

Comment: There's simply no way to do that because the target of any delegate is kept as `object` and therefore necessarily boxed if it's a value type.

Comment: Imagine if the original instance is a local variable (on the stack for the sake of discussion), and that delegate's lifetime exceeded the scope of the method. When that delegate was called, it could refer to a memory location that is invalid or belongs to another method's local variable space. That would be quite unsafe.

Comment: technically, you can avoid the boxing, but any approach to avoiding the boxing would necessarily involve making a new object, which would just be boxing but without using the language feature that does it for you.

Comment: Can the method be static? If so it should not require boxing. If not, and it needs to access members of the struct, then as mentioned in other comments, boxing is required to ensure access to those members.

Comment: The method can't be static because otherwise it can't access any data stored in the struct. 

If I make a static method on struct that will accept the instance of a struct then the created delegate will actually instantiate an instance of a closure. I'm trying to avoid this as well. 

Unfortunately, I can't use a static field as a temporary storage since the code is executed concurrently.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to avoid boxing allocations in this case